# Could not find accessor when binding LiveData in XML

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am trying to Bind a `LiveData<Result<String>>` to a `TextView` using DataBinding. The "Result" is a sealed class used to wrap my response from DataSource.

But no matter what I do I am getting this error:

> Could not find accessor com.saiful.gotravel.domain.Result.data

**Result.kt**

```
sealed class Result<out R> {

data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Result<T>()
data class Error(val exception: Exception) : Result<Nothing>()
object Loading : Result<Nothing>()

override fun toString(): String {
    return when (this) {
        is Success<*> -> "Success[data=$data]"
        is Error -> "Error[exception=$exception]"
        Loading -> "Loading"
    }
}
}
```

**SearchUseCase.kt**

```
class SearchUseCase @Inject constructor():UseCase<String, String> (){
override suspend fun invoke(params: String): LiveData<Result<String>> {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.Main){MutableLiveData<Result<String>>().apply { value =Result.Success("Successful Search Result") }}
}
}
```

**SearchViewModel.kt**

```
class SearchViewModel @Inject constructor(searchUseCase: SearchUseCase) : ViewModel() {
val text:LiveData<Result<String>> = liveData (Dispatchers.IO){
    //Returns a  LiveData<Result<String>>
    emitSource(searchUseCase("This is a LiveData string"))
}}
```

**SearchFragment.kt**

```
class SearchFragment : DaggerFragment() {

@Inject
lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

private lateinit var binding: FragmentSearchBinding

private val viewModel by viewModels<SearchViewModel> { viewModelFactory }

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {


    binding = FragmentSearchBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false).apply {
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        vm = viewModel
    }
    return binding.root
}}
```

**XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.saiful.gotravel.ui.search.SearchViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.search.SearchFragment">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{vm.text.data}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

Can anyone help me to find out What I am doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that only `Success` subtype of `Result` has data property, but in layout you are calling `vm.text.data` where `text` has type of `Result`. That's why compiler can't resolve that property. You can use explicit cast to solve that problem like `(vm.text as? Result.Success)?.data` - it will be better to do that in special `@BindingAdapter` function.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that.

Comment: @ConstOrVar I tried to use it. But you can not use "as" in XML. So the only way to do this is using `@BindingAdapter`

Comment: You can only use java syntax inside databinding layout. `as` - kotlin specific syntax. That's why I advise you to use special `BindingAdapter`